# FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE on activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    }
}
```

if i press button back, app is stunt on 10-15 seconds. 
in log write:

```
D/ANRAppManager: !!! It is not under singleton mode, U can't use it. !!!
I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
D/dalvikvm: dump native stack for : main
D/dalvikvm: unwind backtrace
D/dalvikvm: get native symbol
D/dalvikvm: format backtrace line
D/dalvikvm: get native done
D/dalvikvm: dump native stack for : Thread-7090
D/dalvikvm: unwind backtrace
D/dalvikvm: get native symbol
D/dalvikvm: format backtrace line
D/dalvikvm: get native done
D/dalvikvm: dump native stack for : Binder_2
D/dalvikvm: unwind backtrace
D/dalvikvm: get native symbol
D/dalvikvm: format backtrace line
D/dalvikvm: get native done
D/dalvikvm: dump native stack for : Binder_1
D/dalvikvm: unwind backtrace
D/dalvikvm: get native symbol
D/dalvikvm: format backtrace line
D/dalvikvm: get native done
D/dalvikvm: dump native stack for : Compiler
D/dalvikvm: unwind backtrace
D/dalvikvm: get native symbol
D/dalvikvm: format backtrace line
D/dalvikvm: get native done
D/dalvikvm: dump native stack for : JDWP
D/dalvikvm: unwind backtrace
D/dalvikvm: get native symbol
D/dalvikvm: format backtrace line
D/dalvikvm: get native done
D/dalvikvm: dump native stack for : GC
D/dalvikvm: unwind backtrace
D/dalvikvm: get native symbol
D/dalvikvm: format backtrace line
D/dalvikvm: get native done
D/dalvikvm: Prepare stack traces for '/data/anr/traces.txt' done
I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

and app crash.

in this file /data/anr/traces.txt: https://pastebin.com/J6qdJjU7

I'm doing something like AppLocker. I want that when the button is pressed back, the activity(app) that is behind this activity closes, and the `activity` that is behind my activity of another application.

any ways to do this functional, not necessary with `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`. how it make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to close the topic, but found another way to block someone else's activity by simply launching my own activity, when I see an application that needs to be blocked

Answer (score -1):

I Hope this will work for you.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

Call this line before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: i am sorry i not probably this method